# Thread-safe "Nifty Counter" (aka, "Schwarz Counter")

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization, c++17

The [code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) for a "Nifty Counter" (aka, a "Schwarz Counter")

```
// Stream.h
#ifndef STREAM_H
#define STREAM_H

struct Stream {
  Stream ();
  ~Stream ();
};
extern Stream& stream; // global stream object

static struct StreamInitializer {
  StreamInitializer ();
  ~StreamInitializer ();
} streamInitializer; // static initializer for every translation unit

#endif // STREAM_H
```

```
// Stream.cpp
#include "Stream.h"

#include <new>         // placement new
#include <type_traits> // aligned_storage

static int nifty_counter; // zero initialized at load time
static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof (Stream), alignof (Stream)>::type
  stream_buf; // memory for the stream object
Stream& stream = reinterpret_cast<Stream&> (stream_buf);

Stream::Stream ()
{
  // initialize things
}
Stream::~Stream ()
{
  // clean-up
} 

StreamInitializer::StreamInitializer ()
{
  if (nifty_counter++ == 0) new (&stream) Stream (); // placement new
}
StreamInitializer::~StreamInitializer ()
{
  if (--nifty_counter == 0) (&stream)->~Stream ();
}
```

*seems* like it would be thread-safe... except for [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

> All non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized as part of program startup, before the execution of the main function begins ...

So far, so good.

> (unless deferred, see below).

Uh oh.

> It is implementation-defined whether dynamic initialization happens-before the first statement of the `main` function (for statics) or the initial function of the thread (for thread-locals), or deferred to happen after.

If the dynamic initialization of at the first Nifty counter `static` object is deferred to happen after the first statement of the `main` function and the first statement of the `main` function creates a thread and that thread accesses `stream`, how can it be guaranteed that the stream object will have been fully initialized in the main thread before it's accessed in the second thread?

Does that code contain a race condition?  If so, how would you fix it?  Use reader/writer locks?

---

**EDIT**: making the counter atomic does *not* address the issue. Even if the counter is atomic, that doesn't guarantee that the constructor has *completed* on the original thread before the object is accessed on the second thread.  Unlike function-local static constructors that are guaranteed to be thread-safe, there's no such guarantee for constructors called via placement `new`.

Comment: Use an atomic counter. Nifty counter stomps all over the cache, so there’s minimal additional disadvantage from making it atomic.

Comment: FWIW libstdc++ uses atomic counters for iostreams initialisers.

Comment: Making the counter atomic doesn't address the issue I pointed out.

Comment: Not counting manually loaded dynamic libraries (which don’t follow lots of C++ rules), implementations do not typically defer initialization despite this allowance, and it’s not clear whether it’s possible to do so consistently.  In practice, that’s enough here.

Comment: By itself an atomic counter doesn't resolve the issue, you need to use it like a semaphore. Look at the libstdc++ implementation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Read the EDIT. Also, specific link?

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/ios_init.cc

Comment: That code looks just like the code here, i.e., doing atomic inc/dec and init/destroy only when 0. Yes, the _call_ to the placement `new` happens only once, but, just like here, I don't see how that code prevents another thread from accessing, say, `cout` _before_ the placement-new constructor call finishes _if_ indeed `main()` has been entered and spawned another thread that accesses `cout`

Comment: No, the code there doesn't look like the code here, atomic increment-and-check vs separate increment and check. I don't know how they avoid accessing cout while its constructor is still running, it could be an interesting question, but I don't think it is terribly important in practice. I would probably just use a mutex instead.

Comment: The code there also does separate increment-and-check. The `if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_S_refcount, 1) == 0)` does an atomic increment, but the `== 0` is _separate_. However, it doesn't matter, since the condition will be true only once. Per another's comment, if you make the code here use `std::atomic<int> nifty_counter`, then the code is the same. Yes, the "accessing `cout` while its constructor is still running" is precisely the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225426/discussion-between-paul-j-lucas-and-n-pronouns-m).

Comment: I have done some tests and came to an unpleasant conclusion. The nifty counter in libstdc++ does NOT work in a multithreaded environment. Sorry about misleading you.

Comment: Yes, unpleasant; but my question is how to make my _own_ nifty counter work in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: not sure whether cppreference change, but it says *"it happens before the first odr-use of any variable with static/thread storage duration defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. If no variable or function is odr-used ..."*, which, afaict, means it would be initialized at least before any use of function defined in `Stream.cpp` (which include `Stream.h` and `streamInitializer`)

Comment: @appleapple I don't see how that helps. As the comments above mention, a function elsewhere running in another thread can reference `cout` _before_ its constructor has completed.

Comment: you can synchronize in the `Init` then, because. before you invoke anything on `cout` the translation unit's `Init` would already complete. (e.g lock on `nifty_counter`)